# Implementing operator less for arrays using fold expressions

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

I am playing around with fold expression in c++17 with the latest clang++.  I tried to implement the less operator for an array using this which I want to use for fixed size strings.

Here is where I got to.  Is there a better way to do this, especially avoiding assigning the index in the expression?

Compiling this using "clang++ test_fold_expr_less.cpp -o test_fold_expr_less -std=c++1z" and the output is here.

```
prompt$ ./test_fold_expr_less
=== less ===
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
1
1

#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

std::uint64_t arr1[8] = {1, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9, 3, 6};
std::uint64_t arr2[8] = {1, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9, 3, 6};
std::uint64_t arr3[8] = {1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 9, 3, 6};
std::uint64_t arr4[8] = {1, 7, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 6};

struct less_t
{
    template < typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I >
    bool impl(T const (& lhs)[N], T const (& rhs)[N], std::index_sequence < I... >) const
    {
      std::size_t i{0};
      if (((i = I, (lhs[I] < rhs[I]) ? true : lhs[I] != rhs[I]) || ...))
          return lhs[i] < rhs[i];
      else
          return false;
    }

    template < typename T, std::size_t N >
    bool operator () (T const (& lhs)[N], T const (& rhs)[N]) const
    {
        return impl(lhs, rhs, std::make_index_sequence < N >());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "=== less ===" << std::endl;
    less_t const less{};
    std::cout << less(arr1, arr2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << less(arr1, arr3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << less(arr1, arr4) << std::endl;

    std::cout << less(arr2, arr1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << less(arr2, arr3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << less(arr2, arr4) << std::endl;

    std::cout << less(arr3, arr1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << less(arr3, arr2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << less(arr3, arr4) << std::endl;

    std::cout << less(arr4, arr1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << less(arr4, arr2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << less(arr4, arr3) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a loop? I could understand why one would want to use a fold-expression for `tuple`s, but why for simple arrays?

Comment: `bool less; auto equal = ((lhs[I] == rhs[I] || (less = lhs[I] < rhs[I], false)) && ...); return !equal && less;` is slightly shorter.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental reason why a side-effect is required in the fold-expression: lexicographical comparison needs to bail out of the computation in two cases (less and greater). The only sane way to bail out in fold-expr is short-circuiting (SC). SC only allows two values (bail out / continue), where we have three cases (greater, less, equal). By mapping the three cases to the boolean for SC, we cannot restore the info we need to return (less / greater or equal).

Comment: @dyp I just realized that your solution is similar to my answer, but smarter. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @DanielFrey It is still ugly :( While the `equal = ` IMO makes sense, neither do I like the side-effect nor the cryptic `!equal && less`.

Comment: I second dyp's comment re loops vs fold-expressions. If you are concerned about loop overhead, the compiler can and will unroll loops on std::array (since the size is known at compile time).

Comment: Thanks for the answers/comments.  I am essentially trying to use fold expressions to unroll loops.

Comment: Clearly we need a trinary operator fold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll start with some observations and hypotheses concerning the use of fold-expressions here.

Essentially, we want to write a lexicographical comparison via a single fold-expression. We want to bail out of the comparisons once we can determine the result. Using a unary left fold

```
(... OP comparison)
```

evaluates to

```
(  ( (comparison(0) OP comparison(1)) OP comparison(2) )...  )
```

The only ways to *not* evaluate the `comparison(I)` are *throwing an exception* in one of the comparisons executed earlier and *short-circuiting*. I don't think using exceptions is a good idea here. So I'll try *short-circuiting*. This requires `OP` to be either `||` or `&&`, and the expression to the left must evaluate to a bool that tells the computation whether or not to continue:

```
(  ( (comparison(0) && comparison(1)) && comparison(2) )...  )

comparison(N) -> bool // continue?
```

In lexicographical comparison, we continue evaluating *if the current elements of the lhs and rhs are equal*. So the value of `comparison(I)` must be `lhs[I] == rhs[I]`:

```
#define comparison(I) (lhs[I] == rhs[I])
```

The result of the whole fold-expression then tells us whether or not both sequences are entirely equal:

```
auto equal = (... && comparison(I));
```

However, by doing this, we lose the information about whether `lhs[I] < rhs[I]` or `lhs[I] > rhs[I]` was the reason we stopped the comparison. We can get this information out of the expression by using a side-effect:

```
#define comparison(I) (less = lhs[I] < rhs[I], lhs[I] == rhs[I])

bool less;
auto equal = (... && comparison(I));
```

At this point, we know either `equal == true` or we can use the value last stored to `less` to determine the overall result:

```
return !equal && less;
```

(If `lhs == rhs` then `!(lhs < rhs)`, so we return false. Otherwise, `lhs != rhs` and we use the result stored in `less`. Therefore, `less` doesn't need to be initialized if we have at least one element in the array.)

There is still room for improvement: We can perform the assignment to `less`, and with it the value computation of `lhs[I] < rhs[I]` only when we need it, that is, only when `lhs[I] != rhs[I]`. Using another short-circuit:

```
#define comparison(I) (lhs[I] == rhs[I] || (less = lhs[I] < rhs[I], false))
//                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'd consider this quite cryptic. The value of the underlined part is always `false` due to the use of a comma-expression. Since `false` is the neutral element of `||`, the whole `|| (..)` only performs a side-effect but doesn't change the value of `comparison(I)`, but this side-effect is only performed if the left-hand side of `||` yields `false`.

One last improvement can be achieved by recognizing that if we never assign to `less`, we know that `lhs == rhs` and we can return `false`.

Combined, we get:

```
bool less = false;
auto equal = (... && (lhs[I] == rhs[I] || (less = lhs[I] < rhs[I], false)));
(void)equal; // we don't need you
return less;
```

---

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct loud
{
    std::uint64_t v;
    loud(int x) : v(x) {}
    static auto& opEqual() { static int v = 0; return v; }
    static auto& opLess() { static int v = 0; return v; }
    friend bool operator==(loud l, loud r) { return opEqual()++, l.v == r.v; }
    friend bool operator<(loud l, loud r) { return opLess()++, l.v < r.v; }

    static void print_stats(std::ostream& o) {
        o << "operator< " << opLess() << " operator== " << opEqual();
    }
    static void reset_stats() {
        opEqual() = opLess() = 0;
    }
};

loud arrs[][8] = {
 {1, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9, 3, 6}
 ,{1, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9, 3, 6}
 ,{1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 9, 3, 6}
 ,{1, 7, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 6}
};

struct less_t
{
    template < typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I >
    bool impl(T const (& lhs)[N], T const (& rhs)[N], std::index_sequence < I... >) const
    {
            bool less = false;
    auto equal = (... && (lhs[I] == rhs[I] || (less = lhs[I] < rhs[I], false)));
    (void)equal; // we don't need you
    return less;
    }

    template < typename T, std::size_t N >
    bool operator () (T const (& lhs)[N], T const (& rhs)[N]) const
    {
        return impl(lhs, rhs, std::make_index_sequence < N >());
    }
};

template<class T, int N>
void test(T const (&lhs)[N], T const (&rhs)[N])
{
    auto const stdres = std::lexicographical_compare(lhs, lhs+N, rhs, rhs+N);
    loud::reset_stats();
    auto const foldres = less_t{}(lhs, rhs);
    std::cout << (stdres == foldres) << " -- ";
    loud::print_stats(std::cout);
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "=== less ===" << std::endl;
    for(auto& lhs : arrs)
           for(auto& rhs : arrs)
                test(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Output -- note I do not print the result of the fold-expression-function, but I compare that result to the result of `std::lexicographical_compare`. `true` therefore means both algorithms produced the same result.

```
=== less ===
true -- operator< 0 operator== 8
true -- operator< 0 operator== 8
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 0 operator== 8
true -- operator< 0 operator== 8
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 0 operator== 8
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 1 operator== 4
true -- operator< 0 operator== 8
```